# Chaining asynchronous functions in node.js w/ sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

During the initialization of my Sails.js app, I need to perform several tasks, one dependent of the other. If any of these tasks return an error, the whole chain should fail and cancel `sails lift`.

Pseudocode:

```
configureApis()
  .then(getServiceStatus)
  .then(setRegionJobs)
  .then(cb)
  .catch(cb)
```

Problem is, each of these functions return Promises (except `cb`, which is the callback function [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172270/how-to-cancel-sails-js-lift-with-a-hook/32173258).

How can I achieve this? Would `async.waterfall` be of any use here?

Comment: async waterfall sounds like it would fit the bill but then again maybe the promises make it more complicated. You could try [promise waterfall](https://github.com/dotSlashLu/promise-waterfall)

Comment: To clarify, "Promise-waterfall extends promise utilities with sequential flow control like **async.waterfall**."

Comment: You probably should not be using the same callback for `then` and `catch` in your promise chain because it will receive different type of arguments in both situations, a result on the previous promise or an error object in the second case.

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with the pure promises approach? I am quite sure the pseudocode you proposed can be directly translated to a valid implementation except for the ambiguous usage of the `cb` function.

Comment: How is that a problem? When each of those functions returns a promise, that rather sounds like the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any functions can become Promise if you wrap it in Promise constructor. It's like:

```
...
.then(function(){ return somePromise(); })
.then(function(){

  return Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    /* do whatever your function here, and call either resolve or reject
     * resolve usually for `positive` or true result
     * reject usually for `negative` or false result, and it's usually an Error object
     */

    someFunction('param1', callback function(err, result){
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(result);
    });

  });

})
.then(function(result){
  /* result from previous Promise can be use here */
})
.catch(function(err){
  /* catch error from any of promises above */
  console.error(err);
});
```